# Cloudformation template for CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

We have an aws setup where we have a test account and a production account.
Our code commit (java lambda's) is in our test account and we want to use CodePipeline to deploy code from here to our test account and production accounts.

I was wondering if anyone is aware of any ready made cloudformation (or cdk) templates that can perform this work?

Thanks
Damien

Comment: Are you talking about this sort of thing or do you need something different: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-cross-account-pipeline

Comment: @matthelliwell looks good. slightly different to my setup in that it uses 3 different accounts but looks good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented that a few days ago using CDK, the idea is to create an IAM Role on the target environment and assume this role when running the codebuild(which runs as part of the code pipeline).

In my case, since the codebuild creates CDK stacks I gave an AdministratorAccess policy to this role.

Later, create new codebuild and attach permissions to codebuild project role.

```js
    // create the codebuild project used by the codepipeline
    const codeBuildProject = new codebuild.PipelineProject(scope, `${props.environment}-${props.pipelineNamePrefix}-codebuild`, {
      projectName: `${props.environment}-${props.pipelineNamePrefix}`,
      buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromSourceFilename('buildspec.yml'),
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
        privileged: true,
        environmentVariables: buildEnvVariables,
        computeType: props.computeType
      },
    })

    // attach permissions to codebuild project role
    codeBuildProject.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: [props.deploymentRoleArn],
      actions: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    }));
```

Be aware that `props.deploymentRoleArn` is the ARN of the role you created on the target environment.

Then, create a new pipeline and add `codeBuildProject` to `codepipelineActions.CodeBuildAction` as `project`:

```js
// create codepipeline to deploy cdk changes
    const codePipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(scope, `${props.environment}-${props.pipelineNamePrefix}-codepipeline`, {
      restartExecutionOnUpdate: false,
      pipelineName: `${props.environment}-${props.pipelineNamePrefix}`,
      stages: [
        {
          stageName: 'Source',
          actions: [
            new codepipelineActions.GitHubSourceAction({
              branch: props.targetBranch,
              oauthToken: gitHubToken,
              owner: props.githubRepositoryOwner,
              repo: props.githubRepositoryName,
              actionName: 'get-sources',
              output: pipelineSourceArtifact,
            })]
        },
        {
          stageName: 'Deploy',
          actions: [
            new codepipelineActions.CodeBuildAction({
              actionName: 'deploy-cdk',
              input: pipelineSourceArtifact,
              type: codepipelineActions.CodeBuildActionType.BUILD,
              project: codeBuildProject
            }),
          ]
        }
      ]
    });
```

The relevant part from above code snippet is `Deploy` stage.The other stage is only required in case you want to get sources from github - More info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codepipeline-actions.GitHubSourceAction.html).

This is the full solution, in case you want to implement something else, Read more about code pipeline actions [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline-actions).

Comment: looks good @Amit. I am new to CDK but would you recommend it over writing direct yaml for CloudFormation?

Comment: With no doubt, CDK is simpler, more straight forward,  and more `"programming"` then writing yaml. In my opinion, CDK is the future of infrastructure as code.
AWS effort a lot of resources and money on CDK- they release a new version every couple of weeks. In case you have more questions- feel free to hit me..

Comment: brilliant stuff Amit. I will give it a try tomorrow and let you know how I get on. thanks for your help

Comment: our lambdas are setup using Sam, do you know is it possible with this approach to execute a sam template as part of the process in order to create the lambda?

Comment: Well, I don't have an example of that. But this should be similar to locally. Where have you found difficulties?

Comment: The difficulty at the minute for me is that my CDK is in 1 repo and my lambda code is in a separate repo. I am trying to create CDK / CloudFormation that can be used accross all our projects lambdas (approx 40)