# With CDK, can it be triggered through a lambda to deploy the stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

CDK is good to building the AWS application stack. As far as I know, we can write CDK code and then use `cdk deploy` to deploy the application stack we created.

But is that possible to programmatically trigger the CDK code? For example, I wrap CDK code into lambda, and trigger it on demand (will pass in some parameters so that the application we create can be customized), and when lambda finishes, we have the application stack created.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? What is the rationale?

Comment: @dmahapatro we have a use case that will deploy some customized container to mimic some IoT devices, it needs to be running until we decide to end the jobs. So this process needs to be fully automated. (Creating a stack with customized number of containers -> do some other work -> delete the stack so all containers will be terminated.)

Comment: This is possible and it's quite understandable why you are looking for this implementation, I have created this method using code build and code pipeline,you can read about it more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60064619/9931092
CDK is meant for this kind of things, you want the template to be saved in source code and deploy it on change, otherwise, why use infrastructure as code ?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to trigger programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

That's possible - but messy.

In that case your Lambda Function just needs to have permissions to talk to CloudFormation and to create all the resources it might need.

Then you get into the mess of triggering the CDK via Code.

There are a couple of people that have tried this, maybe this helps with your research:

- [How to package AWS CDK into Lambda layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379916/how-to-package-aws-cdk-into-lambda-layer/60399178#60399178) (Stack Overflow)
- [How to deploy CDK app via Lambda](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2637) (Github)

Depending on your use case it might be worth considering doing this via CodePipeline or have users provision infrastructure via Service Catalogue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The [@aws-cdk/cli-lib-alpha](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/cli-lib-alpha-readme.html) module *"Provides a library to interact with the AWS CDK CLI programmatically from jsii supported languages".*

⚠️ At the time of writing, though, the module is "highly experimental". It has incomplete command coverage (`deploy`, `synth`, `destroy`, `list`) and currently supports JavaScript/TypeScript only.

```js
cli = AwsCdkCli.fromCdkAppDirectory("/path/to/cdk/app");

await cli.deploy({
  stacks: ['MyTestStack'],
});
```

For further usage examples see the [test cases](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/cli-lib-alpha/test/commands.test.ts) in the aws-cdk repo.